# data-placeholder and jQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Is there a simple way to have a default text in the textbox using jQueryUI's autocomplete ?
I have tried using data-placeholder but it doesn't seem to work.

I have searched online, and people suggest using the textbox value to display the text, and clear it on focus. But then I would need to change the font style just for the default text, and check onKeyUp when the text is manually erased etc...

Is there no easier way to do this ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: You can use placeholder attribute, interpreted by recent browser, but for old browser you'll need to code it as you explained (you may use some plugins, but behaviour will be the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people will use a span that is positioned to be over the text box. When the text box gets focus then you hide the span. When the text box blurs and has a value, you don't show it. If it doesn't have a value then you can show it again.

You can style the span however you want independently of the text box so you would not have to change the font style on the text box itself. You would have to subscribe to the focus and blur events, but it would be much easier if you created a jQuery plugin to do this. In fact, I'm sure there are ones that already exist that do this.